# Sql Query in Postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, query

I am trying to execute a query but I am stuck. I have two tables A and B. The a table has columns gid, geometry(line-string) and value which cells is empty , the B table has got 3 columns gid, geometry(Point) and km. I want to find from the A table the start and end point of every line-string and compare with the points of table B if the start and end points of line-string is match with points from table B then i want to compare the values of points start and end which match with one point for start and one for the end and save the bigger value in the empty column of table A.

This is the query I am using.

```
SELECT * FROM r ,e where ST_Equals(ST_Startpoint(r.geom),.geo) LIMIT 10;
```

But i didnt take a result the query running

Comment: what's the problem? Is there an error? Unexpected result?

Comment: error : column r.startx does not exist
LINE 4:  (R.startX=E.X AND R.startY=E.Y) OR (R.endX=E.X AND R.endY=E...

Comment: You need to quote column names that have upper case letters, this is a common gotcha in postgres. So you need to write R."startX". In general, avoid using upper case in Postgres, as quoting is a major pita imho. Also, while there is nothing wrong with it, it is a bit pointless have a table called r and then aliasing it as R. You would be better off just writing r."startx"

Comment: why not something like : WHERE ST_Equals(ST_Startpoint(r.geom),e.geom) OR ST.Equals(ST_Equals(r.ST_Endpoint(r.geom),e.geom) (if both geoms are in same srid)

Comment: @simplexio. I have updated the question with the actual error the OP is getting -- it is to do with upper case table/column names, though I agree that ST_Equals would also be cleaner.

Comment: @John Barça , That is reason why i left comment also  your answer seems to be correct

Comment: You have significantly changed the original question, based on my answer, it would probably have been better to ask a new one. Anyway, what is the error? And shouldn't it be, e.geo?

Comment: There are no error is still running when stop say run out of memory

Comment: How big are the tables? Do they have spatial indizes?

Comment: To make sense of the first paragraph of your question: You have a table of linestrings r and a table of points e. You expect to find both endpoints of every linestring exactly once in the point table. You want to enter the bigger from both values of column "e.km" into the column "r.value". Is this the task you want to achieve?

Comment: This exactly , I find any direct endpoint of linestring table  and match each one of them on the points table and you fit in me pass the corresponding value in the table with the lanes
@Redoute

Comment: @vagelis Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. Perhaps you should look for a support forum in your native language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres column and table names are **not case sensitive** and everything is converted to lower case before executing the query, see [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Therefore,

```
SELECT SomeColumn FROM SomeTable
```

becomes

```
SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable
```

unless you write it as

```
SELECT "SomeColumn" FROM "SomeTable"
```

In my view this is messy, especially when dealing with SQL clients, as you will have to also escape the quotes, so best to just use lower case table/column names from the start. If you are not in a position to change this, then in you case, the offending line can be rewritten as:

```
FROM r INNER JOIN e ON 
(r."startX"=e."X" AND r."startY"=e."Y") OR (r."endX"=e."X" AND r."endY"=e."Y");
```

I would also suggest that you not alias a lower case table name such as r or e as R and E, as otherwise you will have to quote those too, and it doesn't make the query clearer or shorter, either.

In short, in Postgres, use upper case for keywords like SELECT, FROM, JOIN and lower case for everything else.

On another note, `ST_X` returns a number, so `ST_X(ST_AsTEXT`(....)) will also fail, once you have fixed the upper case issue. Just use `ST_X(ST_Transfrom(geom, 4326))` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching for identical points only, the bounding boxes intersect
operator "&&" will be most efficient. In case your tables don't have spatial
indizes, create them:

```
CREATE INDEX ON r USING gist (geom);
CREATE INDEX ON e USING gist (geo);
```

Then for each linestring lookup the matching endpoints and the bigger km value:

```
UPDATE r
    SET value = greatest(e1.km, e2.km)
    FROM e e1, e e2
    WHERE e1.geo && ST_StartPoint(r.geom) AND
          e2.geo && ST_EndPoint(r.geom));
```

This will give correct results only if every start- and endpoint is found
exactly once in your table e.